# Magento2.1.9 Mini Cart Items Issue?

Tags: magento2

I have upgrade magento 2.1.6 to 2.1.9 but problem is Minicart shows no product even when I have products in cart.
My site work on local not work on live .

PFA

[image]

Please Give me any solution?